# What could be causing my TestNG test methods to 'vanish' when parallel is enabled?

Tags: testng

TLDR - When I run a large-ish selenium test suite with parallel enabled, a bunch of test methods 'vanish' - They are no longer reported as passed, failed or skipped, just seemingly gone. I'm hoping someone might be able to provide me with some pointers on how to troubleshoot the problem.

When I run my test set normally, it takes about 10 hours (ergh), with just under 800 individual tests. It's normally run through maven and surefire, with a suite.xml file something like this...

```
<suite name="MainSuite" time-out="1800000" verbose="10">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.example.selenium2webdriver.testng.listener.StatsdSuiteListener"/>
  </listeners>
  <test name="AllTests">
    <groups>
      <run>
        <exclude name="windowsonly"/>
        <exclude name="upgrade"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
    <packages>
      <package name="com.example.selenium.*"/>
      <package name="com.example.selenium2webdriver.tests.*"/>
    </packages>
  </test>
</suite>
```

and I get a surefire-reports/testng-results.xml file which starts with something like this...

```
<testng-results skipped="7" failed="8" total="789" passed="774">
  <reporter-output></reporter-output>
  <suite name="MainSuite" duration-ms="35693671" started-at="2016-12-28T08:49:22Z" finished-at="2016-12-28T18:44:16Z">
```

Now, the problem. If I add `parallel="methods" thread-count="2"` to the suite declaration there in the hope of speeding up the overall runtime, I now see the following at the top of my surefire-reports/testng-results.xml file...

```
<testng-results skipped="5" failed="9" total="45" passed="31">
  <reporter-output></reporter-output>
  <suite name="MainSuite" duration-ms="1818150" started-at="2017-01-08T08:50:25Z" finished-at="2017-01-08T09:20:43Z">
```

Sure, it's lots faster, but suddenly I'm only seeing about 5% of my tests being reported (and looking at the target machine suggests that the missing ones are in fact not being run).

So, my question, after all that, is 'how can I ensure all my tests are still run when I enable the parallel mode'? Or, failing a simple answer, how can I troubleshoot this further to either pin down the problem in my setup, or distill it down to a reproducible bug which could be reported.

---

A few random other pieces of background/info in case they're relevant/helpful.

I'm using TestNG 6.10, (And also saw this on 6.9.10).

In the hope of being able to provide a more reproducible example, I used javaparser to stub out all the actual test method content (leaving the annotations etc in place). The resulting test set ran everything in just a few seconds, and no longer seemed to suffer the problem regardless of the parallel configuration. I imagine that suggests that either the problem is timing specific, or that something in the tests themselves triggers the problem.

The specific tests which are run in parallel are not consistent, nor is the count. Over a few runs, I've seen total hit around 100 at most.

Looking closer at the surefire-reports/testng-results.xml file, /testng-results/suite/groups/group does seem to list ever test method...For example, I see...

```
<group name="DeleteCollectionCLI">
  <method signature="DeleteCollectionCLI.deleteCollectionfromCLI()[pri:0, instance:com.example.selenium.cli.DeleteCollectionCLI@e3c0e40]" name="deleteCollectionfromCLI"class="com.example.selenium.cli.DeleteCollectionCLI"/>
</group>
<!--  DeleteCollectionCLI  -->
```

...but neither that class nor that method are not represented under the /testng-results/suite/test section of the results

Comment: You should open an issue on http://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues but it will be difficult to help you because it looks difficult to reproduce the issue with a simple sample. Maybe you can start to remove layers from the stack and run the suite with testng command line.

Comment: Yeah, I went to do so, but saw the 'post here and on the google group first' note and figured I'd do my due diligence. Feels like it must be a timing issue (since presumably test method content shouldn't be able to do this, so maybe I can repro it by replacing the method content with sleeps or something)

Comment: Yes, the note is used to avoid questions on the issue tracker. But here, it looks a real issue which should be reported if you are able to reproduce it.

Comment: Ok, will do - Thanks. Someone on the Google Group suggested adding a couple of listeners to the suite to narrow things down, so I'll try that, then raise it in the issue tracker.

Comment: My suggestion is that you are avoiding errors on configuration stage which are caused by parallel execution, may be browser providing or something like this. As result your tests crashed without any data in test results. It would be nice if you could share your project to check it.

Comment: More digging lead me to notice that timeout on the suite there is clearly misconfigured (30 mins when the tests take hours), so that explains why the tests vanish, but not why it works without parallel (the timeout must be ignored in that case for some reason). More discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/VVwgxGT6pFQ